# Google geochart not taking text data

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to use Google Marker Geocharts for plotting user location event data. Here is the example code of google which i'm using..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

        function drawMarkersMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['City',   'Population', 'Area'],
                ['Rome',      2761477,    1285.31],
                ['Milan',     1324110,    181.76]
            ]);         

            var options = {
                region: 'IT',
                displayMode: 'markers',
                colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Above is working fine.But, the moment i try to use user location event data(as showing in below)..

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City',   'Event', 'Year'],
    ['Rome',      'Birth',    '1981'],
    ['Milan',     'Schooling',    '1995-2005']
]);
```

It's started showing this error - 
[image]

I searched a lot in google but, did not get any reliable answer. Any idea how to resolve this error ?

Regards